# Unable to connect to access database with php

Tags: php

I have the following code trying to connect to an access database

```
<?php 
 $dbName = $_Server["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = "C:\xampp\htdocs\college\db\phpDB.accdb";
 IF(!file_exists($dbName)) {
     die("could not find db");
 }
 $db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
 echo 'Connected to database<br />';


$sql = "SELECT TestForTest FROM tblTesttable";
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row)
        {
        print $row['TestForTest'] . '<br />';

        }

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $db = null;
 ?>
```

This is the path to database

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\college\db\phpDB.accdb
```

phpinfo() details

```
PDO drivers mysql, odbc, sqlite

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $

PDO_ODBC

PDO Driver for ODBC (Win32) enabled
ODBC Connection Pooling Enabled, strict matching
```

But I get the error message: could not find db, i have also tried using .realpath but no luck

I'm very new to php and would appreciate any help with this connection problem

Thanks

/------------------------Solved--------------------------/

I should have used I'm a fool, url to db should have been C:\xampp\htdocs\college\db\phpDB.accdb works now

Comment: What is the path of the file, which contain your shared source code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, all installed files are in C:\xampp

Comment: I mean that script, which you wanna run (first code block you shared)

Comment: Ok that is here C:\xampp\htdocs\college\index.php

Comment: Try to update your path to DB: `$dbName = "db/phpDB.accdb";`

Comment: Had tried that before got error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: 63 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x314c Thread 0x3f1c DBC 0x8c877cc Jet'.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\college\index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\college\index.php(15): PDO->__construct('odbc:Driver={Mi...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\college\index.php on line 15

Comment: I'm a fool, url to db should have been C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\college\\db\\phpDB.accdb works now

Comment: :D oh yes, you're right!